# Joining another table in query with CASE and END

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join row from table of users on base of userID from below's query. But I dont know how to access userID value. Right now I am receiving rows : userID:[number]. On base of this userID i want to add columns from table users so I will receive: userID:[number], firstName (from users table), lastName(from users table) etc. So to sum it up: I want to join data from users table on base of result of below's query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE 
        WHEN user1_id = ? 
        THEN user2_id 
        ELSE user1_id 
    END userID 
FROM conversations 
WHERE ? IN (user2_id,user1_id)
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: You're not using anything from the `users` table, what's the point of joining?

Comment: I basically want to join users table data on base of result of this query : ``` SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE 
        WHEN user1_id = ? 
        THEN user2_id 
        ELSE user1_id 
    END userID 
FROM conversations 
WHERE ? IN (user2_id,user1_id)```

Answer (score 1):

Use the case expression in your join condition:

```
FROM conversations 
    INNER JOIN users on CASE  WHEN user1_id = ? THEN user2_id ELSE user1_id END = users.id`  b
```

That being said, given your overall logic, I would think this would be identical to the much simpler

```
FROM conversations
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ?
```

which feels weird, but nets you the same results.

You could also solve with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT 
         CASE 
           WHEN user1_id = ? 
           THEN user2_id 
           ELSE user1_id 
           END userID 
         FROM conversations 
         WHERE ? IN (user2_id,user1_id)
      ) dt
      INNER JOIN users on dt.userID = users.id
```

I suspect this would give you the same results as the queries above though.

Comment: I am sorry, I updated question so its probably more clear now.

Comment: I also added a subquery version. Each of these should work fine for you needs.